# how to put labels over the bars google.charts.Bar()

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I need to put labels over my google.chart.Bar **(not google.visualization.BarChart)** the chart is correctly visualized but only shows values on mouse over the bars,please helpme!.

[without mouse over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLM4y.png)
[with mouse over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDjxM.png)

the data is taked from hidden inputs... here the code :

```
    var data3 = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Ambitos', 'Programados', 'Terminados',{ role: 'style' }],
      ['ex', parseInt(document.getElementById("sumex").value),(parseInt(document.getElementById("sumex").value))-( parseInt(document.getElementById("sumpex").value)),document.getElementById("sumex").value],
      ['ma', parseInt(document.getElementById("summa").value),(parseInt(document.getElementById("summa").value))-( parseInt(document.getElementById("sumpma").value)),document.getElementById("summa").value],
      ['mo', parseInt(document.getElementById("summo").value),(parseInt(document.getElementById("summo").value))-( parseInt(document.getElementById("sumpmo").value)),document.getElementById("summo").value],
      ['re', parseInt(document.getElementById("sumre").value),(parseInt(document.getElementById("sumre").value))-( parseInt(document.getElementById("sumpre").value)),document.getElementById("sumre").value],
      ['tx', parseInt(document.getElementById("sumtx").value),(parseInt(document.getElementById("sumtx").value))-( parseInt(document.getElementById("sumptx").value)),document.getElementById("sumtx").value]]);

    var view3 = new google.visualization.DataView(data3);
    view3.setColumns([0,1,2,
                   { calc: "stringify",
                     sourceColumn: 3,
                     type: "string",
                     role: "annotation" },3]);

    var options3 = {
        legend: { position: "none" },          
                chart: {
                title: 'Resumen General',
                subtitle: 'programados v/s terminados'},
       series: {},
         axes: {  y: {
                      distance: {label: ''}, } },
      chartArea : { width:"95%", height:"80%"} };

      var chart3 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barras'));
      chart3.draw(data3, options3);
```

p.d. sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately, annotations (bar labels) are not supported on *Material* charts

recommend using *Core* chart, with the following option instead...

```
theme: 'material'
```

an separate annotation column should be added for each series column,
that should have annotations

when using a DataView to add annotation columns,
be sure to draw the chart using the view (`view3`),
instead of the original data table (`data3`)

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data3 = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Ambitos', 'Programados', 'Terminados',{ role: 'style' }],
      ['ex', 8,(8)-(6),''],
      ['ma', 6,(6)-(4),''],
      ['mo', 4,(4)-(2),''],
      ['re', 2,(2)-(1),''],
      ['tx', 1,(1)-(0),'']]);

    var view3 = new google.visualization.DataView(data3);
    view3.setColumns([0,
      1,
      {
        calc: "stringify",
        sourceColumn: 1,
        type: "string",
        role: "annotation"
      },
      2,
      {
        calc: "stringify",
        sourceColumn: 2,
        type: "string",
        role: "annotation"
      },
      3
    ]);

    var options3 = {
      legend: { position: "none" },
      chart: {
        title: 'Resumen General',
        subtitle: 'programados v/s terminados'
      },
      series: {},
      axes: {
        y: {
          distance: {label: ''},
        }
      },
      chartArea : {
        width:"95%",
        height:"80%"
      },
      theme: 'material'
    };

    var chart3 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('barras'));
    chart3.draw(view3, options3);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="barras"></div>
```

---

**note**: list of options unavailable to *Material* --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

Comment: I have an issue with datatable and google.visualization.Query which I exposed here to look for a possibile solution. Would you like to have a look? LaLiberté is also on it (I hope) [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-visualization-api/mBLpyopTLEU/8YLDK0qJCwAJ)

Comment: I will look later, on vacation this week