# How to add annotation to Google Bar Chart where dataset comes from Google Sheet

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am looking to create a market share bar chart based on today's current value, it's pulling the dataset from a Google Sheet that updates daily. But I can't fathom out how to include the value inside each individual bar, for example, id like to show the returned value of each market share either above or inside each bar chart.

I believe Google refers to it as annotations, I have been messing with the code and don't seem to get getting very far.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#labeling-bars

I've looked/read many examples including Google's documentation but could not find one that used an external data source, such as Sheets. (need to use sheets as its going to update daily (hopefully)

I have placed the code in codepen as well as below https://codepen.io/xgstq/pen/zYOyELL

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
      <!-- Include Charts -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT Y, AA LIMIT 8');
        var query = new google.visualization.Query(
        'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dljjxpn1GFJC7O0tu6bMw_tEp7tYBLYFPo6UTVrA63s/gviz/tq?gid=0&headers=1&tq=' + queryString);
            query.send(handleQueryResponse);
      }

      function handleQueryResponse(response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
          alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
          return;
        }

        var options = {
              chart: {
                title: 'Company Performance',
                subtitle: 'Todays Market Share',
              },
              bars: 'vertical', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
              bar: { groupWidth: "90%" },
              legend: { position: 'none' },
            };

      var data = response.getDataTable();
      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));
          chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
    }

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Call the Chart -->
      <div id="barchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

The dataset source is in this sheet (columns Y and AA >> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dljjxpn1GFJC7O0tu6bMw_tEp7tYBLYFPo6UTVrA63s/

Comment: you can use a data view to add annotations, however, annotations are not supported by _material_ charts, need to use classic bar / column chart -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43545446/5090771)

Comment: I have the same exact problem here and I would like to ask WhiteHat to provide a working example at this point, since I really don't understand how it is the same issue as the answer he linked.
Or at least, if it is, it is very hard to implement.
Because in our case data comes from a url after all: we CANNOT write down MANUALLY a dataset within the code; and if we had to then why use a spreadsheet as database??
It would be GREAT, IDEAL if we could provide a couple or more of additional columns WITHIN our query to the sheet to use as data for annotations. CAPS is for better reading not shout

Comment: The one difference in WhiteHat's answer regarding where your data comes from, whether locally defined or via a spreadsheet query, doesn't matter because the solution is independent of that.  Focus on how a DataView is used to change the role of a column of (string) data in your DataTable into a column used for annotations.