# How to show a value in google chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I am creating a google chart everything is going fine but I am having an issue. The issue is, I have spent a lot of time displaying chart values at the top OR inside the bar chart but no luck.

I can do it in other google charts it is as easy as pie but  not in the one I am trying. Please let me know how to do it. What I am doing wrong?

```
<script>
    var mainArray = [];

    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', '');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Number of Paid Customers');
        data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
        data.addColumn('number', 'Amount of Paid Customers');
        data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});

        data.addRows(mainArray);

        var options = {
            colors: ['#42af58', '#ff8b3e'],
            height: 300,
            annotations: {
                alwaysOutside: true,
                textStyle: {
                  fontSize: 14,
                  color: '#000',
                  auraColor: 'none'
                }
            },
            chart: {
                title: '',
                subtitle: ''
            },
            series: {
                0: {axis: 'NumberOfPaidCustomers'},
             },
            axes: {
                y: {
                    NumberOfPaidCustomers: {label: 'Number of Paid Customers'},
                 }
            },
            hAxis: {
                title: '',
                viewWindow: {
                    min: [7, 30, 0],
                    max: [17, 30, 0]
                }
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Rating (scale of 1-10)'
            }
        };
        var materialChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div_one'));
        materialChart.draw(data, options);
     }

    $(document).ready(function () {  


        $("#drawBtn").click(function(){

             data ={"8":{"startDate":"20-09-2019","course_id":13,"venue_id":14,"location_id":19821,"total_course_location":2,"total_location_sale":370},"7":{"startDate":"28-06-2019","course_id":13,"venue_id":14,"location_id":19818,"total_course_location":1,"total_location_sale":185},"6":{"startDate":"08-03-2019","course_id":13,"venue_id":14,"location_id":18100,"total_course_location":7,"total_location_sale":1545},"5":{"startDate":"08-02-2019","course_id":13,"venue_id":14,"location_id":18099,"total_course_location":9,"total_location_sale":1815},"4":{"startDate":"11-01-2019","course_id":13,"venue_id":14,"location_id":18098,"total_course_location":13,"total_location_sale":2555},"3":{"startDate":"14-12-2018","course_id":13,"venue_id":14,"location_id":17345,"total_course_location":16,"total_location_sale":3260},"2":{"startDate":"16-11-2018","course_id":13,"venue_id":14,"location_id":17344,"total_course_location":10,"total_location_sale":2050},"1":{"startDate":"19-10-2018","course_id":13,"venue_id":14,"location_id":17343,"total_course_location":8,"total_location_sale":1730}};

                    var dataArray = [];
                    var count = 0;
                    mainArray = [];
                     $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                        count = count + 1;
                        dataArray = [];
                        dataArray.push(element.startDate);
                        dataArray.push(element.total_course_location);
                        dataArray.push("'"+element.total_course_location+"'");
                        dataArray.push(0);
                        dataArray.push('');
                        mainArray.push(dataArray);
                     });
                    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
                    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        });


    });

 </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you checked this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43534064/how-to-put-labels-over-the-bars-google-charts-bar